# Token generated via Passport Laravel use in Adonis JS

Tags: laravel, authentication, adonis.js, passport-jwt

I want to use the same token generated from Laravel Passport in AdonisJS for the generic API. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried using the same secret key and decrypting your token at adonisjs middleware?

Comment: Yes @AsadJivani I have already tried this